# Setting attached properties on parent ContentPresenter from a DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, attached-properties, contentpresenter

I have a `Grid` and somewhere in it a `ContentControl`:

```
<Grid Name="OuterGrid">
    <!-- some controls on the grid -->

    <ContentControl Name="dbg1" Content="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource SBATemplateSelector}"></ContentControl>

    <!-- some more controls on the grid -->
</Grid>
```

The templateselector is not really interesting:

```
<src:SBATemplateSelector x:Key="SBATemplateSelector"
    NormalTemplate="{StaticResource SBAreaTemplate1}"
    BigTemplate="{StaticResource SBAreaTemplate2}" />
```

But from the templates I'd like to give the content and position it in 'OuterGrid', by setting the `Grid.Row` etc. attached properties:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SBAreaTemplate1" DataType="src:XCViewModel">
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter"> <!-- should go for only the 'parent' contentpresenter -->
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="4" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="10" />
        </Style>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>

    <Border Name="sbAreaBorder" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
        <ScrollViewer Name="sblbScroller" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <ItemsControl Name="notRelevantListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource NotRelevantSelector}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

so I don't even want Binding, just setting properties to static values. No matter what I do I can't get the properties to take effect on the `ContentPresenter` of the `DataTemplate`.

There are almost usable solutions (e.g. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cc9ed724-600e-415a-b775-bae09eea66f8/cant-use-attached-properties-inside-a-datatemplate?forum=wpf) but they always apply an `ItemsControl` - I don't have an `ItemsControl`, I want the positioning to work for the whole `DataTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

The `ContentTemplate` cannot set the `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` attached property of the `ContentControl`. The template is only applied to the `Content` of the `ContentControl`.

But you could to this programmatically in your `ContentTemplateSelector`:

```
public class SBATemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            ContentPresenter cp = container as ContentPresenter;
            if (cp != null)
            {
                ContentControl cc = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(cp) as ContentControl;
                if (cc != null)
                {
                    Grid.SetRow(cc, 4);
                    Grid.SetColumn(cc, 0);
                    Grid.SetRowSpan(cc, 5);
                    Grid.SetColumnSpan(cc, 10);
                }
            }

        }
        ...
    }
}
```